# SQL Server 2008 : calculate 32nd value of a give decimal number

Tags: sql-server-2008

Could some one please provide me an example or formula on how to calculate 32nd (32ticks) of a given decimal number in SQL Server 2008.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: forumala to calculate 32nd of a given number....that is commonly used in Finance(mortgages).

Comment: What is a 32nd of a given number? 32nd what? Why do you mention `32ticks`?

Comment: This question needs more information, apparently "32nd" isn't enough information to go on in order to understand what you're asking for.

Comment: the questuin is how to calculate 32nd ticks of a give number

Comment: But we don't know what "32nd ticks" is..... You need to tell us. Do you have any information about it? Like a link to an explanation of what it is?

Comment: What is a tick of a number? I know about ticks that relate to timers and clocks, but not to numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, 32 ticks is the same as a point which is 1% of the original loan, so simply divide the number by 100; a tick would be obtained by dividing by 3200.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm understanding your question at all, but if you are looking for the digit in the 32nd place of a decimal, here's what would give it to you:

```
select substring(cast(@somedec as varchar(50)), CHARINDEX('.', cast(@somedec as varchar(50))) + 32, 1)
```

If that is *not* what you're looking for, please clarify.

Comment: Am sorry, the query does not return anything. It just returns empty row